# shiny app to eliminate plotted experimental artefacts

Tags: r, shiny

I have a 2-D dataset that I have plotted below. As pointed out by the arrows, there are two experimental artefacts that I would like to eliminate from the dataset.

```
head(df)
data      CTCF 
1 -20000 0.9220779        
2 -19999 0.9220779        
3 -19998 0.9350649        
4 -19997 0.9350649
5 -19996 0.9220779       
6 -19995 0.9220779
```

[click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SizQ4.png)

i have a shiny app taken from the shiny gallery to reveal the position on the x and y axis of a clicked point in the dataset.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot_click"),
  verbatimTextOutput("info")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(df[,1], df[,2])
  })

  output$info <- renderText({
    paste0("x=", input$plot_click$x, "\ny=", input$plot_click$y)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is useful for identifying exactly where the artefacts are but I would rather be able to manipulate the data at those positions to get rid of the artefacts.

Does anyone know how to manipulate the data after it has been clicked on the graph? I would like to be able to click on the regions where the artefacts lie so that they are reactively set to the mean value y-axis value. Even better it would be cool if you could click and drag over a region rather than having to click the points individually...

UPDATE 
I have tried the following:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot_click"),
  tableOutput("tab")
)

    server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(df[,1], df[,2])
  })

  output$info<-renderText({class(as.numeric(input$plot_click$x))})
  data_new<-eventReactive(input$plot_click,{
     data=df
     data[round(as.numeric(input$plot_click$x)), 2]=mean(data[,2])
     data  
  })
 output$tab<-renderTable({data_new()})
 }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But the output replaces the entire column with the average rather than just replacing the clicked positions

```
data    CTCF    
-20000  0.71 #average of entire column  
-19999  0.71    
-19998  0.71    
-19997  0.71    
-19996  0.71
```

And I don't know enough about shiny in terms of how it handles objects to be able to fix this....
Thanks

Comment: Can you share a sample data?

Comment: hi sorry for the wait sample data are included at top now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace the clicked point with the mean replace

`data[round(as.numeric(input$plot_click$x)), 2]=mean(data[,2])` of your code with

`data[which(data[,1] == round(as.numeric(input$plot_click$x))),2] = mean(data[,2])`

To click and drag over a region you can change your `eventReactive` as follows:

```
 data_new<-eventReactive(input$plot_brush,{
      data=df
      rowmin <- which(data[,1] == round(as.numeric(input$plot_brush$xmin)))
      rowmax <- which(data[,1] == round(as.numeric(input$plot_brush$xmax)))
      data[rowmin:rowmax,2] = mean(data[,2])
      data  
    })
```

[EDIT]: As per @user7792658 comments,I forgot to mention that in the ui the `plotOutput` should be as follows:

```
plotOutput("plot1", brush = "plot_brush")
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi SBista, Thank you so much your first strategy works! however for the dragging: I changed your input$plot_click to to the way that I had it (plot_click) and from there used the exact same code: 

data_new<-eventReactive(input$plot_brush,{
   data=df
    rowmin <- .....
    ..... etc.
but when I try to drag across the graph it drags the entire graph like a ".png" , when I click on an individual point it returns: Warning: argument of length 0

Comment: got it to work by setting the brush argument of plotOutput to 'plot_brush'

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot to mention it. Will add that in the answer in case anyone reads it later.

Comment: Hi SBista, Thank you so much again- I was wondering is there any way to make the values of the non-reactive variable permanently retain the changes made rather than the original incorrect data frame being replotted each time?